# Switch translations in python and gettext

Tags: python, internationalization, gettext

I have the following code which should display two lines of English text and one line of Romanian text between the two English ones, but it only displays English text (the translation switching doesn't work):

main.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.7

import gettext
gettext.install('messages', '../i18n', unicode=True)

import card

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = card.Rank()
    print x.j, x.a, x.q, x.k

    ro = gettext.translation('messages', localedir='../i18n', languages=['ro'])
    ro.install()

    print x.j, x.a, x.q, x.k

    en = gettext.translation('messages', localedir='../i18n', languages=['en'])
    en.install()

    print x.j, x.a, x.q, x.k
```

card.py

```
class Suit(object):
    clubs = _('Clubs'),
    diamonds = _('Diamonds'),
    hearts = _('Hearts'),
    spades = _('Spades')


class Rank(object):
    j = _('Jack')
    q = _('Queen')
    k = _('King')
    a = _('Ace')


class Card(object):
    # ...
```

My directory structure is as follows:

```
.
├── i18n
│   ├── en
│   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │       └── messages.mo
│   ├── en.po
│   ├── en_US.po
│   ├── ro
│   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │       └── messages.mo
│   ├── ro.po
│   └── ro.pot
├── Makefile
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── card.py
    ├── card.pyc
    ├── deck.py
    └── main.py
```

I used `xgettext` and `msgfmt` to generate the `.po` and `.mo` files.

The problem is that if I only load a single language, the text gets translated (I have to do this as the sole thing before any output is displayed).

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.7
import gettext

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ro = gettext.translation('messages', localedir='../i18n', languages=['ro'])
    ro.install()

    import card
    x = card.Rank()
    print x.j, x.a, x.q, x.k
```

But if I want to change languages on the fly the output made by the first code snippet presented above won't be translated.

What I'm doing wrong? What did I understand wrong from the docs?

Answer (score 2):

All gettext.install() does is define the _() function as something that translates text. In your first example, you do `x = card.Rank()` before your ro.install() call - and so the only time that `j = _('Jack')` is called, _() translates it into the default English. Subsequently, _() gets redefined to Romanian - but it never gets called again, and so never gets retranslated.

I expect this will work:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.7

import gettext
gettext.install('messages', '../i18n', unicode=True)

import card

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = card.Rank()
    print x.j, x.a, x.q, x.k

    ro = gettext.translation('messages', localedir='../i18n', languages=['ro'])
    ro.install()

    x = card.Rank()
    print x.j, x.a, x.q, x.k

    en = gettext.translation('messages', localedir='../i18n', languages=['en'])
    en.install()

    x = card.Rank()
    print x.j, x.a, x.q, x.k
```

Comment: Yeah, because translation in your code is done during class loading as the _() function is not called in the constructor but as part of class definition. The Explanation given in this answer is correct, but the example has overlooked that detail

Answer (score 1):

Translations are typically for end-users, not developers. So leave your strings as literals in the code and only translate when you display them:

```
class Rank(object):
    j = 'Jack'
    q = 'Queen'
    k = 'King'
    a = 'Ace'
```

...

```
    x = card.Rank()
    print _(x.j), _(x.a), _(x.q), _(x.k)
```

Note that the string extraction tools won't be able to find these strings anymore unless you call them with _() somewhere in your code.

If you don't want to add the strings to the translation files manually, you could add something like this to the module:

```
if False:
    _('Jack')
    _('Queen')
    _('King')
    _('Ace')
```

Or this:

```
assert(_('Jack'))
assert(_('Queen'))
assert(_('King'))
assert(_('Ace'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = card.Rank() 
print _(x.j), _(x.a), _(x.q), _(x.k)
```

*Totally works!*

Yes, the string literals must be somewhere in ur code.

The string literals *need not be in the same module* which displays the text. Putting the string literals in the same module is not pretty on the eyes (not OOP).

Successfully tested using py v2.7 / gtk v2.24.10 / gettext 0.18.1

```
python
import gtk 
gtk.gtk_version
(2, 24, 10)

gettext --version
gettext (GNU gettext-runtime) 0.18.1
```

**Disclaimer**
Don't attempt this before getting gettext working for your python application. Including being able to change locales (languages) on the fly. These are no small feats. This will remove 99% of the confusion. Then it'll either work or it won't. I'm saying it'll work!

Comment: I'll try this in the evening. But I'm curious: what does gtk have to do with my question?

Comment: Your right! In this case, gtk is not necessary.

Just gettext is often used when packaging applications. A good percentage of which use a ui windowing library.